# MySql Regex Find and Replace for Wordpress

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, wordpress

This is my first time here so excuse me if I'm missing anything.

I'm trying to perform a regex find and replace in my SQL Wordpress post content to strip out unnecessary  `div` and `span` tags.

I've used this regex in text editing programs to do the same task:

`<[/]?(span|div|[ovwxp]:\w+)[^>]*?>`

What's the best way to approach this as an SQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about running that as SQL, but [Search RegEx](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-regex/) is a good plugin to be able to search and replace with Grep through all posts and pages from the WP admin area.

Answer (score 0):

You can use REGEXP_REPLACE in MySQL 8

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = REGEXP_REPLACE(post_content, '<[/]?(span|div|[ovwxp]:\w+)[^>]*?>', '')
```