# Wordpress links to images from posts broken

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, permalinks, posts

I have a Wordpress site with many broken links to the images from my posts.

e.g. http://www.currentinspiration.com/words/communication/

This started after I changed my permalink.

All new posts and links from images are working correctly after the permalink change.

If I go to an image with a broken link, edit the post, edit the image, click Link to Image button. The link is updated correctly.

old bad link: http://currentinspiration.com/2010/02/24/communication/caveman-images1/

new working link: //currentinspiration.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/caveman-images1.jpg

I've started this manually, but there are too many images.

I've read some about regular expression. It seem this could be done automatically with the regex or broken links checker plugin.

Does anyone know the regular expression I can use?

or

Is the an easier way to make the change?

Thanks

Comment: Regex plugin looks good.  Don't know what to type into the search replace?

Answer (score 0):

i found a similar question here [MySql Regex Find and Replace for Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684085/mysql-regex-find-and-replace-for-wordpress) and this plugin looks promising http://wordpress.org/plugins/search-regex/

Comment: The regex plugin looks like it will do the job.  Not sure what to out in the search replace.

Comment: i haven't used the plugin so don't know if it requires "escaping" symbols, but i would start here, search for `2010/02/24/communication/` and replace with `wp-content/uploads/2010/02/`